# How do I copy the whole content of a pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, copy-paste, transfer

Helllo,

I want to transfer a pdf to my c# program using .net 3.5. I know, there are libs for that, but I am not allowed to use such. So I came up with the idea to just copy the content of the pdf file manually and then transform it to my datatable. Because I want it to work automatically I am using this code:

```
Process Adope = new Process();
Adope.StartInfo.FileName = fd.FileName.ToString();
Adope.StartInfo.Arguments = fd.FileName.ToString();
Adope.Start();
IntPtr Adobe_handler = IntPtr.Zero;


while (elapsed_Time.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 5000) {
    Adobe_handler = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", fd.SafeFileName + " - Adobe Reader");
        if (Adobe_handler != IntPtr.Zero) {
            break; 
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
}
if (Adobe_handler == IntPtr.Zero) {
    MessageBox.Show("Adobe is not running");
    return;
}

elapsed_Time.Stop();

Clipboard.Clear();

SetForegroundWindow(Adobe_handler);
elapsed_Time.Start();
while (pdf_Info.Equals("")&&elapsed_Time.ElapsedMilliseconds<=10000) {
    Clipboard.Clear();
    SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
    SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
    pdf_Info = Clipboard.GetText().ToString();
}
elapsed_Time.Stop();
Adope.Close();
```

It works... Sometimes. So I am looking for a better way or a improvement. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: *It works... Sometimes* ... what happen when it doesn't work? Any error?

Comment: Not really. The pdf file opens. But sometimes I get a error message that there was a problem copying it to clipboard and sometimes the adobe reader freezes and must be terminated via task manager